# Nethack for Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, nethack

I'm looking for a good version of Nethack to run on my Windows Mobile phone.  I currently have Windows NetHack graphical version 3.4.3, and it kind of drives me a little nuts, moreso from a usability and playability standpoint.

I don't know if this is because I'm trying to run it on a phone, but I'm hoping somebody here has a better suggestion for a client.

Now, onto specific wishes, so this doesn't get modded into subjective-oblivion....

- Needs to have good interaction with a physical keyboard -- for instance, I kept typing <kbd>C</kbd> to attempt to name my kitten, but I kept getting an invalid direction...not sure if this is a result of the keyboard mapping or something else, but basically my current client doesn't seem to follow commands listed within the help
- Good/decent tileset - I'm not a terribly huge fan of learning the ASCII representations of the Nethack-verse...this may be a bit of a slap in the face to the nature of the game, but I really really like having the graphical tiles to show me what's going on.
- Decent GUI - it'd be really nice if a shortlist of commands was available so that I could easily remember that typing <kbd>E</kbd> allows me to engrave
- Decent save system - if I previously had a game going under a character named 'E' I will be unable to overwrite this saved game...I need to dig around in my OS files to find where the save game is and delete it by hand.

---

**EDIT**

Ok, since it seems like the answer to my previous question is no, then I will follow up with this one (it should still fall within the realm of the title).

Is there some sort of disconnect between the vanilla Nethack commands and the WinMo client?  As I mention above, I am having problems in using keyboard commands with the gameplay.  I have tried both with my physical keyboard, and with the onscreen keyboard in the client, and no matter what I tried, I could not name my kitten.  I have not gone through all the commands, but I've noticed that there are other little issues that I can't remember offhand.

---

**EDIT 2**

[Nethack 3.4.3 Windows Mobile Client](http://www.nethack.org/v343/ports/download-wince.html)

Comment: I'm having troubles finding any other Nethack clients for Windows Mobile aside from the 3.4.3. This is going to be difficult.

Comment: @Mana, no other versions of Nethack have been since released, so it's kind of a given...

Comment: Now it would help to link to the client you are using, @espais, although the problem is likely a bug with the software.

Comment: @badp: done and done

Comment: Hang on, I'm installing a WinCE emulator.

Comment: Gah, I can't install software with the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was at least able to resolve my issue with naming.

My assumption was that I would type <kbd>C</kbd> and follow it up with a direction.

However, with the Windows Mobile client, you type <kbd>C</kbd>, and then need to tap the screen in order to select the thing to identify, otherwise the dialogue will not pop up fo r naming.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which file you need to find for windows mobile, but I'm pretty sure that you can change a file, which will change the controls, which will at least fix your controls problem.